# Rsync, include only certain files types excluding some directories

Tags: linux, unix, rsync

I want to rsync only certain file types (e.g. `.py`) and I want to exclude some directories (e.g. `venv`).

This is what I have tried:

```
rsync -avz --include='*/' --exclude='venv/' --include='*.py' --exclude='*' /tmp/src/ /tmp/dest/
```

But it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

With `rsync` you do not need to use `--include="*.py"` to include `'*.py'` files in the copy. The `--include` option will only include files that have been excluded by `--exclude=` before. `rsync` specifies `**` as the wildcard specifier. For example, if you want to copy all `.py` files in the current directory (and subdirectories), but not copy anything from the `venc` directory, you can do something similar to:

```
rsync -uav --exclude="venc" **.py destination
```

(**note** -a implies `-rlptgoD`)

which would recursively copy all `.py` files in present working directory to `destination` excluding the `venc` directory.

To recursively copy only `*.py` files from all directories below the current path excluding any `venc` directories, you can build a temporary file with the results of `find` containing the `*.py` files and exclude files containing `venc/` as part of the path, and then transfer all filenames in the temporary file using the `--files-from` and `--no-R` (no relative) options to `rsync` as:

```
$ find /path/to -type f -name "*.py" | grep -v 'venc/' > tmpfile \
rsync -uav --no-R --files-from=tmpfile / host:/dest/dir \
rm tmpfile
```

This will capture all `*.py` files in any subdirectories excluding all directories including the name `venc/` and anything below them. The `--no-R` option is needed to prevent the absolute filenames in `tmpfile` from be taken as relative to the current working directory.

Comment: This does not copy the *.py files in the subdirectories.